# Is this integral solvable analytically?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I have this integral that comes from my research with some Fourier Transforms of spectrum functions:

$$ G(\tau) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\Lambda x} x^n e^{i \tau ( c_1 - c_2 e^{-c_3 x} ) } dx $$

where $c_1, c_2, c_3, \Lambda, n > 0$.

The only way for me now is to use a series expansion of the term  $e^{i \tau ( c_1 - c_2 e^{-c_3 x} ) }$ and take the first few terms. However, I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do it.

== EDIT ===

$$ n \quad \epsilon \quad \mathbb{Z}^+  $$, so only positive integers.

Comment: You can factor out $\exp(i\tau c_1)$ to make the integral a little simpler, as well as scale $x$ to get rid of one of the constants. $c_3$ is probably the best choice.

Comment: Maybe it would help to see that $\frac{d^n}{d a^n} e^{-ax}=x^n e^{-ax}$:

Comment: @TymaGaidash I tried that and you end up differentiating terms of the form $\gamma(a,z)/z^a$ with respect to $a$, where $\gamma$ is the lower incomplete gamma function. These get nasty fast. Though perhaps one could make a recursion over $n$ for them.

Comment: If you make $x$ a complex variable, then your integrand is an entire function with no singularities. That means the integral of it about any closed path is $0$. A common trick then is to find a closed path depending on a parameter $R$ such that one section of the path becomes the real interval $[0,\infty)$ as $R \to \infty$, another section of the path is something you can integrate, and you can show that the integral along the rest of the path goes to $0$ as $R\to \infty$. Then your integral has to be the opposite of the section you can calculate.

Comment: @PaulSinclair excellent idea. Thanks a ton. I used to solve complex integrals with choosing paths on Riemann sheets before for waveguide problems. I think I can try as you suggested. Could you give me some reference to a simpler example with the trick applied to one parameter ?

Comment: It is a common technique, though usually, on the portion of the closed path representing the original integral does not go to $0$, and the value of the integral comes from the singularities enclosed by the Reisdue theorem. But in this case, there are no singularities, so any value has to come from other portions of the path. You want a path from $0$ to $\infty$ along which the integrand is simplified enough to be calculated. The closed path will follow this path out so some distance $R$ from $0$, follow a circle arc aound to the positive real line, then run back in to $0$. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) The $e^{-\Lambda x}$ factor in the integrand should be sufficient to show that the integration along the circle arc $\to 0$ as $R\to \infty$. The portion along the real axis becomes the opposite of your integral, while the selected path from $0$ to $\infty$ would supply the value. But note that I don't have such a path in mind. A suitable one would have to be identified. For example, you might try setting $t = c_2e^{-c_3x}$, or turning it around, $x = -\frac1{c_3}\ln\frac t{c_2}$ (where $x$ is considered a complex variable), though the $x^n$ factor is problematic then.

Comment: I have only: $$\int_0^{\infty } \exp (-\Lambda  x) x^n \exp (i \tau  (\text{c1}-\text{c2} \exp (-\text{c3} x))) \, dx=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{i \text{c1} \tau } (\text{c3} j+\Lambda
   )^{-1-n} (-i \text{c2} \tau )^j \Gamma (1+n)}{j!}$$  for: `n=1` is:$\frac{e^{i \text{c1} \tau } \, _2F_2\left(\frac{\Lambda }{\text{c3}},\frac{\Lambda }{\text{c3}};\frac{\Lambda }{\text{c3}}+1,\frac{\Lambda }{\text{c3}}+1;-i \text{c2} \tau
   \right)}{\Lambda ^2}$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for the detailed reply. I got the rationale behind your approach. Indeed it's difficult here, but I will try to find a suitable path if possible. For this I may do some numerical simulations to see how this function behaves in the complex plane.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk thanks a lot. How did you arrive at this sum? And is it also doable for n>1? In fact in the question I forgot to mention that “n” can be only integers. I didn't have this knowledge of this parameter before I asked the question.

Comment: @CfourPiO.  $$\exp (-\Lambda  x) x^n \exp (i \tau  (\text{c1}-\text{c2} \exp (-\text{c3} x)))=e^{-x \Lambda +i \text{c1} \tau } x^n \sum _{j=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{\left(-i \text{c2} e^{-\text{c3} x} \tau \right)^j}{j!}$$ and then you need only integrate. For `n=2` is:$$\frac{2 e^{i \text{c1} \tau } \, _3F_3\left(\frac{\Lambda }{\text{c3}},\frac{\Lambda }{\text{c3}},\frac{\Lambda }{\text{c3}};\frac{\Lambda
   }{\text{c3}}+1,\frac{\Lambda }{\text{c3}}+1,\frac{\Lambda }{\text{c3}}+1;-i \text{c2} \tau \right)}{\Lambda ^3}$$.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk this solution works like magic. It matches my numerical simulations (for me n is actually more than 6 so the constant becomes $\frac{n \ !}{\Lambda^{n+1}}$). Please write it an answer and I will accept it. Is there any physical significance of these hypergeomertic functions? I found that they are solutions to differential equations. Do you know which applications these differential equations can arise in?